# Aprove function does not increase allowance of ERC20

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

I am trying to implement a simple token transfer to a Vault but I'm having trouble approving the transaction and when I run tests using foundry, I receive this error:

[FAIL. Reason: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance] testDeposit() (gas: 86770)

My code is for the deposit function is here:

```
function deposit(uint256 amount) external {
    console.log("RANDOM inside deposit = ");
    console.log(IERC20(underlyingToken).balanceOf(msg.sender));

    console.log("msg sender =");
    console.log(msg.sender);

    console.log("approve = ");
    console.log(IERC20(underlyingToken).approve(address(this), amount));

    // IERC20(underlyingToken).approve(msg.sender, amount);

    console.log("RANDOM inside deposit after approve = ");
    console.log(IERC20(underlyingToken).allowance(msg.sender, address(this)));


    IERC20(underlyingToken).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    // // totalDeposited += amount;
    IPool(aavePool).supply(underlyingToken, amount, address(this), 0);

    totalUnderlyingDeposited += amount;
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the vault give itself an allowance for the sender.  That would defeat the whole point of the approval mechanism.

What your code `IERC20(underlyingToken).approve(address(this), amount)` actually does is give the vault permission to transfer any of its own tokens using `transferFrom`.  Obviously this is a bit silly since the vault can just use `transfer` to do that.

Your commented-out code `// IERC20(underlyingToken).approve(msg.sender, amount);`, as you probably figured out, lets the sender transfer the vault's tokens.

The only way to let the vault do `transferFrom(msg.sender, ..., ...)` is if the sender interacts directly with the ERC20 by calling `approve` him/herself.

This means the user will need to do two transactions to do the first deposit into the vault: 1) approve the vault for an allowance sufficient to cover the deposit 2) do the deposit.

If the approval is for an "infinite" amount (max uint256), then subsequent deposits only require a single transaction each; however, this is not considered wise from a security standpoint.